# How do I determine the maximum and minimum value for an Oracle NUMBER column?

Tags: oracle, numbers, max, minimum

Is there a simple formula for determining the maximum and minimum values for an Oracle NUMBER column with (p, s)?

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure, it is something like:

from - 10 ** (p - s) to 10 ** (p - s)

p is number of significant decimal digits, and s is number of digits after period. So

NUMBER(6, 2)

can store values from -9999.99 to +9999.99.